# If you have a DFA M, how do you construct a new NFA that accepts L(M) and {e}?

Tags: automata

Suppose you're given a DFA $M$ with a 5 tuple of $(Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_0, F)$.

How do you construct an NFA that accepts $L(M)$ and $\{\varepsilon\}$, the set containing the empty string? I know that a DFA is an NFA.

My thought is that you would simply add a new transition from the start state to the accepting state, which takes epsilon/the empty string.

For example (eps. is epsilon/empty string):

[image]

Since I've added an empty string transition, the machine is no longer a DFA, but it is an an NFA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but there's a slight bug.
If you add an $\varepsilon$-transition from the start state to all accepting states, then the new machine recognizes a subtly different language.
Let $L_k = \{w_1 \cdots w_k : \exists u_1, \dots, u_{k-1} \in L(M) \text{ such that } w_1 u_1 w_2 \cdots u_{k-1} w_k \in L(M)\}$.
Note that $L_1 = L(M)$.
This new machine will recognize the union of the $L_k$, i.e., it recognizes $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} L_k$.

Instead, you can create a new state $q_{\text{empty}}$, add an $\varepsilon$-transition from $q_0$ to $q_{\text{empty}}$, and take the new set of accepting states to be $F \cup \{q_{\text{empty}}\}$.

Comment: This is an important distinction, particularly to a beginner. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I previously made a mistake in determining the language accepted by your proposed construction; see the updated answer for a correct description of what happens when you add an $\varepsilon$-transition from the start state to the final states. My previous answer implicitly assumed there were no transitions leading back to the start state.